# MS Teams language selection for MSbot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a MS Chatbot and deployed to MS Teams Channel. I want to set the language of the bot based on the language settings in MS Teams channel.

[image]

How to retrieve the Channel settings in my bot?

MG Graph API explorer gives me information on Channels but not on this settings. However, I get an option called 'preferredLangauge' which is always null. I even changed the language in Settings but still this 'preferredLangauge' does not change.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure about the channel settings, but on the messages your bot receives from the users, there's a locale value set that might be of use?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the settings for your native Teams Application, not the settings for a Channel. Channels do not have Language setting:

[image]

For 1:1 conversations you could request the `preferredLanguage` property for the User:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/preferredLanguage
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users({id})/preferredLanguage",
    "value": "en-US"
}
```

For 1:*n* conversations you can use the `preferredLanguage` property of the Organization:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization?$select=preferredLanguage

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#organization(preferredLanguage)",
    "value": [
        {
            "preferredLanguage": "en"
        }
    ]
}
```